# 3つの3次元ポイントを軸とする2次元に変換するには

Tags: python, numpy

3つの3次元ベクトルA,B,Cがあり、ABを2次元空間のx軸に、ACを2次元空間のy軸にそれぞれ当てはめるような座標変換をするにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

[image: 3つの3次元ベクトルから新しい3次元系に変換]
素人考えでは下記のような操作ができればと思っているのですが、具体的なプログラムが組めません…。

1. ABが新しい3次元系のx軸になるように回転する
2. ACが新しい3次元系のxy平面上にくるように回転する
3. ACが新しい3次元系のy軸にくるようカメラ？のz座標を調整する

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 新しい座標系の z 軸の定義が必要だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

takoika さんの回答を参考に、[グラム・シュミットの正規直交化法](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E7%9B%B4%E4%BA%A4%E5%8C%96%E6%B3%95)を使ってベクトルを変換できました。
プログラムとテストケース、図を載せておきます。

[image: 動作確認用]

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def transform(a, b, c, p):
...     v1 = b - a
...     v2 = c - a
...     u1 = v1
...     u1 = u1 / np.linalg.norm(u1)
...     u2 = v2 - (np.dot(u1, v2) / np.dot(u1, u1)) * u1
...     u2 = u2 / np.linalg.norm(u2)
...     u3 = np.cross(u1, u2)
...     u3 = u3 / np.linalg.norm(u3)
...     rot = np.array([u1, u2, u3])
...     return np.dot(rot, p - a)
... 
>>> A = np.array((2, 0, 0))
>>> B = np.array((2, 2, 0))
>>> C = np.array((2, 2, 2))
>>> p1 = np.array((0, 1, 0))
>>> transform(A, B, C, p1)[:2]
array([ 1.,  0.])
>>> p2 = np.array((0, 1, 1))
>>> transform(A, B, C, p2)[:2]
array([ 1.,  1.])
>>> p3 = np.array((0, 0, 1))
>>> transform(A, B, C, p3)[:2]
array([ 0.,  1.])
>>> p4 = np.array((3, 0, 1))
>>> transform(A, B, C, p4)[:2]
array([ 0.,  1.])
```

Comment: 回答しておきながら申し訳ありませんが，確認です．実現したかったことは与えられた座標pを平面ABCに射影する，ABとそれに直行するベクトルを基底とする2次元座標系に写す．ということですか?

Comment: 「座標pを平面ABCに射影する」はやりたいことです。「ABとそれに直行するベクトルを基底とする2次元座標系‌​に写す」は違って、「ABとACを直交させてから2次元座標系‌​に写す」を実現したいのですが、このプログラムは実現できていません。質問文中の1～3の操作のうち、1と2までを実装できた、というところです。

Comment: 直行化せず単純にAB,ACとそれに直行するベクトルで作る空間に写してz成分をとりのぞけばよいのではないですか?

Answer (score 0):

与えられた座標pに対して
1. まずAが原点になるようにAを平行移動する `(p-A)`
2. ABがx軸， ACがy軸, ABとACのつくる平面に直行する軸をz軸とする(右手系で考える)， そのような変換をする回転行列Rをかける `R*(p-A)`

どのように回転行列をつくるかを説明します． まずベクトルABを正規化したものをベクトルbとする． また同様にベクトルACの正規化したものをcとする． ABC面と直行したベクトルをdとしこれはbとcの外積になっている． このときb,c,dに回転行列Rを作用するとそれぞれx,y,z軸になるようにしたいので以下をみたす．
Rb = (1, 0, 0)
Rc = (0, 1, 0)
Rd = (0, 0, 1)
これをとくと R^-1 = (b, c, d) , R^-1は3x3の行列でたてベクトルb,c,dをならべたもの．
よって R = (b, c, d)^-1 = (b, c, cross(b, c))^-1

```
import numpy

A = numpy.array([0.1,0.1,0.1])
B = numpy.array([2,1,5])
C = numpy.array([1,10,-1])

b = (B-A)
b = b/numpy.linalg.norm(b)
c = (C-A)
c = c/numpy.linalg.norm(c)
d = numpy.cross(b, c)

R = numpy.linalg.inv(numpy.array([b, c, d]))

def transform(p):
    return numpy.dot(R, p-A)
```